# Singular fit in the lme4 package but not in the nlme package?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I was fitting a model in nlme using the lme function and noticed a low correlation among the random effects of nearly 0. When I refit the model in lmer I got a singular fit error. Why is this happening? Does it mean that the model fit in NLME is also singular but not throwing a warning?

```
    > fitlme <- lme(systolic~  Age + Gender + stress + time*gac_score_z + time*affect_balance_z + 
+                 I(time^2)*affect_balance_z+ I(time^2)*gac_score_z, 
+               random = (~time|id), 
+               data = df.longs)
> 
> fitlmer <- lmer(systolic ~ Age + Gender + stress + time*gac_score_z + time*affect_balance_z + 
+                   I(time^2)*affect_balance_z+ I(time^2)*gac_score_z+ (1+time|id),  data = df.longs)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
> 
> summary(fitlme)
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
  Data: df.longs 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1248.768 1299.586 -608.3839

Random effects:
 Formula: ~time | id
 Structure: General positive-definite, Log-Cholesky parametrization
            StdDev       Corr  
(Intercept) 8.9931231865 (Intr)
time        0.0004353713 0     
Residual    4.1077036479       

Fixed effects:  systolic ~ Age + Gender + stress + time * gac_score_z + time *      affect_balance_z + I(time^2) * affect_balance_z + I(time^2) *      gac_score_z 
                               Value Std.Error  DF    t-value p-value
(Intercept)                123.56475  6.960353 120  17.752656  0.0000
Age                          0.16842  0.151355  57   1.112776  0.2705
Gender                      -4.19316  2.800376  57  -1.497358  0.1398
stress                      -1.04416  1.534135  57  -0.680620  0.4989
time                        19.55561  1.319878 120  14.816227  0.0000
gac_score_z                 -2.57675  1.442237  57  -1.786634  0.0793
affect_balance_z             0.82076  1.500465  57   0.547006  0.5865
I(time^2)                  -10.36193  0.634049 120 -16.342472  0.0000
time:gac_score_z            -4.08433  1.437921 120  -2.840444  0.0053
time:affect_balance_z        0.63016  1.422551 120   0.442982  0.6586
affect_balance_z:I(time^2)  -0.37480  0.683371 120  -0.548455  0.5844
gac_score_z:I(time^2)        1.90949  0.690755 120   2.764354  0.0066
 Correlation: 
                           (Intr) Age    Gender stress time   gc_sc_ affc__ I(t^2) tm:g__ tm:f__ a__:I(
Age                        -0.600                                                                      
Gender                     -0.501 -0.027                                                               
stress                     -0.544  0.197 -0.253                                                        
time                       -0.044  0.000  0.000  0.000                                                 
gac_score_z                -0.061  0.223 -0.246  0.180  0.006                                          
affect_balance_z           -0.261 -0.120  0.286  0.213 -0.002 -0.368                                   
I(time^2)                   0.030  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.961 -0.004  0.001                            
time:gac_score_z            0.001  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.026 -0.230  0.078  0.025                     
time:affect_balance_z       0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.009  0.082 -0.219 -0.009 -0.355              
affect_balance_z:I(time^2)  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.009 -0.057  0.152  0.009  0.341 -0.961       
gac_score_z:I(time^2)      -0.001  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.025  0.160 -0.054 -0.026 -0.961  0.341 -0.355

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
-2.74654638 -0.48250117 -0.06360532  0.50527120  2.51683596 

Number of Observations: 189
Number of Groups: 63 
> 
> summary(fitlmer)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: systolic ~ Age + Gender + stress + time * gac_score_z + time *      affect_balance_z + I(time^2) * affect_balance_z + I(time^2) *  
    gac_score_z + (1 + time | id)
   Data: df.longs

REML criterion at convergence: 1216.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.75138 -0.46769 -0.06306  0.54614  2.51743 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       (Intercept) 86.22804 9.2859        
          time         0.08594 0.2932   -1.00
 Residual             16.78427 4.0969        
Number of obs: 189, groups:  id, 63

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                123.8495     6.9330  57.6852  17.864  < 2e-16 ***
Age                          0.1698     0.1506  57.0498   1.127  0.26434    
Gender                      -4.2705     2.7865  57.0498  -1.533  0.13090    
stress                      -1.1111     1.5265  57.0498  -0.728  0.46967    
time                        19.5556     1.3169 120.1649  14.850  < 2e-16 ***
gac_score_z                 -2.5708     1.4754  62.4867  -1.742  0.08636 .  
affect_balance_z             0.7809     1.5310  63.1388   0.510  0.61182    
I(time^2)                  -10.3619     0.6324 119.9904 -16.386  < 2e-16 ***
time:gac_score_z            -4.0843     1.4347 120.1649  -2.847  0.00519 ** 
time:affect_balance_z        0.6302     1.4194 120.1649   0.444  0.65786    
affect_balance_z:I(time^2)  -0.3748     0.6816 119.9904  -0.550  0.58341    
gac_score_z:I(time^2)        1.9095     0.6889 119.9904   2.772  0.00647 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Age    Gender stress time   gc_sc_ affc__ I(t^2) tm:g__ tm:f__ a__:I(
Age         -0.600                                                                      
Gender      -0.500 -0.027                                                               
stress      -0.543  0.197 -0.253                                                        
time        -0.049  0.000  0.000  0.000                                                 
gac_score_z -0.060  0.217 -0.239  0.175  0.006                                          
affct_blnc_ -0.254 -0.117  0.279  0.207 -0.002 -0.367                                   
I(time^2)    0.030  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.960 -0.004  0.001                            
tm:gc_scr_z  0.001  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.026 -0.248  0.084  0.025                     
tm:ffct_bl_  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.009  0.088 -0.237 -0.009 -0.355              
aff__:I(^2)  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000 -0.009 -0.055  0.148  0.009  0.341 -0.960       
gc_s_:I(^2) -0.001  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.025  0.156 -0.053 -0.026 -0.960  0.341 -0.355
optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```